# Why bsDatepicker show error after deleting manually the text box and then selecting a date?

Tags: angular, forms, validation

I was able to integrate bsDatepicker in my Angular 5 app and also applied
customize validation for various scenarios.

I have 1 problem with a specific scenario:
Clicking on the textbox, the date picker appear, then click backspace to
delete the date manually. So far so good.
While deleting the date picker is still open, after finish deleting I select
date from the picker and I see my **required** custom error message.

I hope it's not related to bsDatepicker. Here some code:
From the template:

```
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="myDate" 
    dateValidator placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy" [ngModelOptions]="{ updateOn: 'blur' }" 
    #myDate="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="mydate" id="myDate" autocomplete="off"
    required bsDatepicker [bsConfig]="dpConfig"> 

<div *ngIf="myDate.errors && (myDate.touched || cFormDirective.submitted)">
    <div class="error_message" *ngIf="myDate.errors?.required">         
            Please enter date                                                
    </div> 
</div>
```

From the import:

```
import {enGbLocale} from 'ngx-bootstrap/locale';
import {BsLocaleService, defineLocale, BsDatepickerConfig} from 'ngx-bootstrap';
```

From the component constructor:

```
enGbLocale.invalidDate = '';
defineLocale('custom locale', enGbLocale); 
this.localeService.use('custom locale');
this.dpConfig.showWeekNumbers = false;                                
this.dpConfig.dateInputFormat = 'MM/DD/YYYY';
```

Please note that after the error shown, if I select date all is fine.
Any idea how to avoid the error from showing in this case ? Thanks.

**UPDATE**

Have a look in the link below:
[enter link description here](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/datepicker#basic)

Scroll down to the examples and you'll see that this is an existing issue.
Again, trigger the picker, select date and delete manually the date. When you delete, the picker is opened, select date and you'll see that it's not copied
to the textbox.

Comment: can you create a stackblitz..

Comment: I've tried but import { BsDatepickerModule } from '../../node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/datepicker'; not recognise there.

Comment: Actually you don't need to go far, I'll update my question and will prove that this is a bug in BsDatepicker